# Is a vav before a verb in the Chumash always a tense changer?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pentateuch-chumash

I know that the vav before a noun can be a vav hachibur (cf http://www.torahmusings.com/2012/12/on-the-prefix-vav/) but in front of a verb it changes tense (past to future and vice versa) and may or may not also include the idea of "and".

But is that tense hipuch inevitably the case? Is understanding of the chumash text driven by this tense change as an absolute rule or is its application selective and controlled by some other understanding which contextualizes (either grammatically or logically) the verb and demands that the vav operate as a vav hahipuch?

Comment: How do you expain this with the word v'ohavto (from shma)?

Comment: On the linked page there is a discussion of that word but in the context it appears that it is possible that the vav in some cases does NOT change tense:

Comment: "The general rule is that in the first-person singular and second-person-masculine singular conjugations, the vav alone doesn’t effect the hipukh; rather a change in syllabic stress – from mil’el to mil’ra – is also required to effect a “reversal” in tense. Some examples in Sh’ma would be v’ahavTA and v’nasaTI, where the CAPS denote the stressed syllable (second-person plural is always mil’ra, eg. v’limadTEM... Otherwise, if it’s mil’el (as in v’aHAVta), then the vav must be only conjunctive, and it’s past tense.

Comment: Please note that it is by no means universally agreed upon that the ו _changes_ the tense, but rather that it indicates which verbal system a verb is a part of, which in turn gives aspectual or modal information about the verb. A provocative review of the persistence of the former view despite the consensus tending toward the latter can be seen [here](https://ejournals.library.ualberta.ca/index.php/jhs/article/view/6201/5235). For concise reviews of what the וs are precisely doing see [this paper](http://www.academia.edu/download/31302503/JoostenAspect.pdf) and. . . (cont.)

Comment: (cont.). . . its [response](http://www.academia.edu/download/30847889/Cook30.pdf). All of this is to say that it would seem that the proper classification of verbs into their syntactic (and semantic?) classes that is accomplished through the identification and interpretation of the וs is indispensable to the meaning, although perhaps in even more ways than the question implies.

Comment: @WAF the two links to academia.edu in your comments are broken for me. Presumably, they point to resources that one needs some sort of permissions to see.

Comment: It seems that there is debate over whether the vav prefix is a linguistic aspect, parsable through the establishing of an overarching grammar or an interpretive aspect, extant through the theological approach to text. Is Rashi citing it as an explanation for a difficulty, or as a translation?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I will try to fix those. Here are the papers: 1) Joosten, Jan. "**Do the finite verbal forms in Biblical Hebrew express aspect**." Journal of Ancient Near East Studies 29 (2002): 49-70. 2) Cook, John A. "**The finite verbal forms in Biblical Hebrew do express aspect**." Journal of the ancient Near Eastern society 30 (2006): 21-35.

Comment: Looking at Yeshayahu 6:3 "וְקָרָא זֶה אֶל זֶה וְאָמַר" which the Chabad translation has (since it is the prophet recalling what he saw in his vision) "And one called to the other and said..." The same line, when used in kedusha, after the timeline of the future action (nekadesh) is established is translated in Artscroll as "And one [angel] will call another and say..."

Comment: @Danno That is interesting. It could very well have to do with recontextualization of the words from the prophecy itself to _t'fila_. The original meaning need not be preserved if the words are being used for a different purpose. Add that to the fact that if you accept the aspectual argument, that verb form should be indeterminate WRT to _tense_, but still perfect(ive) in both instances. So the work of the _vav_ could be consistent. (It could also be due to different individual translators working on each...)

Comment: @WAF I was just alerted to this http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37625&st=&pgnum=8 and Perek 5, 41 seems to indicate that (though my Hebrew is rusty) it is not absolute but is contextual.

Comment: That entry is describing something very similar to what @EzraHoerster called the "consecutive vav", which arose to fill some of the conceptual space occupied by what you might call the "conversive vav". I believe its use is supposed to be limited to sequences of "suffix form" narrative verbs, whose tense information is determined by the first one in the sequence. [Here](http://www.animatedhebrew.com/charts/sequence_tense_terms_bw.pdf) is a handy chart I stumbled on for some comparison of terms in popular grammars. Whether the concept underlying these is _hipuch_ is a long standing debate. . .

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question. @Ezra's answer is not entirely correct. In many cases, a vav at the beginning of a verb does indicate a tense change (vav hahipuch). But, the key to knowing if it is this way or not is to view the accent on the main part of the verb, itself.

See for example, [Vayikra 10:9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14081&st=&pgnum=117&hilite=) which is written as:

> וא**כל**תי חטאת היום

since the accent is on the 2nd syllable, it is past tense, and, therefore, the vav means "and".

Had the Torah wanted to use this as a vav hipuch to change the past tense to future (which would have been incorrect, here), the accent would have been on the last syllable making it ואכל**תי**.